# How can I transform a list into a csv?

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

I have this values that come from a sql query to postgresql (i changed the color of the rows to show that firts value is the same)

```
**('80255', 'GRN', Decimal('4.00000000000000000000'))**
('80425', 'GRN', Decimal('1.00000000000000000000'))
**('80255', 'BCN', Decimal('1.00000000000000000000'))**
('80425', 'BCN', Decimal('22.0000000000000000'))
**('80255', 'PT', Decimal('2.0000000000000000'))**
('80425', 'PT', Decimal('5.0000000000000000'))
...
```

I want to transform to the next, into a csv file.

```
80255;4;1;2
80425;1;22;5
```

For each sku (like  80425), i want to put the inventory in each location(GRN/BCN/PT)

Answer (score 1):

A good tool to use when you have a key which has multiple values is [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) The `defaultdict` container creates a new object for each new key and when it encounters a key that's already present it operates on that key; in this case the operation is the list method `.append()`.

And then you can write to a file using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module

```
import csv, collections as co, decimal as dc, itertools as it

fromdb = [('80255', 'GRN', dc.Decimal('4.00000000000000000000'))
         ,('80425', 'GRN', dc.Decimal('1.00000000000000000000'))
         ,('80255', 'BCN', dc.Decimal('1.00000000000000000000'))
         ,('80425', 'BCN', dc.Decimal('22.0000000000000000'))
         ,('80255', 'PT', dc.Decimal('2.0000000000000000'))
         ,('80425', 'PT', dc.Decimal('5.0000000000000000'))]

tocsv = co.defaultdict(list)
for i in fromdb:
    tocsv[i[0]].append(i[-1])

with open('output.txt','wb') as f:
    cw = csv.writer(f,delimiter=';')
    for k,v in tocsv.items():
        cw.writerow(tuple(it.chain((k,),v)))
```

Comment: +1 Looks like you're relying on the order of `GRN -> BCN -> PT` rows.  The question doesn't say you can do that, and even if it did, some number may be missing a `BCN` row altogether.

Comment: Oh, I see your point. It is correct that there is nothing in my code that sorts the results from the database, nor is there a check for a missing value.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from @bernie's nice answer, here's a variant with more comments, that doesn't depend on the row order, and that can deal with missing values:

```
# import collections and abbreviate it as co
import collections as co
import decimal as dc
import csv

fromdb = [('80255', 'GRN', dc.Decimal('4.00000000000000000000'))
         ,('80425', 'GRN', dc.Decimal('1.00000000000000000000'))
         ,('80255', 'BCN', dc.Decimal('1.00000000000000000000'))
         ,('80425', 'BCN', dc.Decimal('22.0000000000000000'))
         ,('80255', 'PT', dc.Decimal('2.0000000000000000'))
         ,('80425', 'PT', dc.Decimal('5.0000000000000000'))]

# Build a dictionary that maps values like '80255'
# to a dictionary containing values for GRN, BCN and PT
tocsv = co.defaultdict(lambda:
    {'GRN': 0, 'BCN': 0, 'PT': 0} )
for i in fromdb:
    # Array index -1 refers to the last element
    # For example, set tocsv['80255']['GRN'] to 4.00
    tocsv[i[0]][i[1]] = i[-1]

with open('output.txt','wb') as f:
    cw = csv.writer(f,delimiter=';')
    # items() returns an iterable of key (k) and value (v) pairs
    # For key '80255', the value will be {'GRN': 4, 'BCN': 1, 'PT': 2}
    for k,v in tocsv.items():
        # writerow() takes an array argument, hence the [] square brackets
        cw.writerow([k, v['GRN'], v['BCN'], v['PT']])
```